# Ordinal Ridge and Lasso Regression in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, statistics, regression

Thank you for taking your time to read my problem.
I have to run Ordinal Ridge and Lasso regression on my dataset. The values that I want to predict are ordinal (5 levels) and I have many predictors (over 60) that are continuous but not all of them are logically significant. So, I would like to run the Ordinal Regression using Lasso and Ridge to find the significant ones.
I am very new to python and I don't know really what to do and appreciate any help from the community.
I have found the mord module (and even if I am using it right), it doesn't provide Ordinal Lasso.
Could anyone help me with this, please?
Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
I have written the following code, I don't get any error and I get an accuracy lower than previous analyses. So, I assume I am making mistake at a point in how I am doing it. I would appreciate it if someone helps me with it.  I guess it could be in scaling, but I don't know how.
"rel" has five values: 1,2,3,4,5 which are my predicted values.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import mord
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale, StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import csv

#defining a function to rotate numbers in an array 
def leftRotatebyOne(arr, n):
    temp = arr[0]
    for i in range(n-1):
        arr[i] = arr[i+1]
    arr[n-1] = temp

#defining OR to do Ordinal Ridge Regression    
OR = mord.OrdinalRidge()

#definign the loop to go through all participants
for s in range(17):

    #reading the data for each participant
    df = pd.read_csv("Complete{0}.csv".format(s+1), index_col=0, header=None).dropna()
    df.index.name = 'subject{0}'.format(s+1)
    df.columns = ["ch{0}".format(i+1) for i in range(64)] +["irrel", "rel"]
    #defining output and predictors
    y = df.rel
    X = df.drop(['rel', 'irrel'], axis=1).astype('float64')

    #an array containig trial numbers
    T = np.array(range(480))

    #defining a matrix to hold the models of all runs(480 one-leave_out) for each participants
    out=np.empty((67,480))

    #runing the model for all trials (each time keeping one out)
    for t in range(480):

        T1 = T[:479]
        T2 = T[479:]   #the last one which is going to be out

        ## Always the last one is going to be out, how it works is that we rotate T, so the last trail changes

        #train samples
        X_train = X.iloc[T1,:]
        y_train = np.array(y.iloc[T1])

        scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)

        #test sample
        X_test = X.iloc[T2,:]
        y_test = np.array(y.iloc[T2])

        #rotating T
        leftRotatebyOne(T,480)

        #runing ordinal ridge regression from the module mord
        OR.fit(scaler.transform(X_train), y_train)
        predicted = OR.predict(scaler.transform(X_test))
        error = mean_squared_error(y_test, predicted)
        coeff = pd.Series(OR.coef_, index=X.columns)

        #getting the accuracy of each prediction
        if predicted == y_test:
            accuracy = 1
        else:
            accuracy = 0

        #having all results in a matrix (each column is for leaving out one of the trials)
        out[:,t]=np.hstack((coeff,predicted,error, accuracy))

    #saving the results for each participant 
    np.savetxt("reg{0}.csv".format(s+1), out, delimiter=',')

 #saving all results in one file
filenames = ["reg{0}.csv".format(i+1) for i in range(17)]
dataframes = [pd.read_csv(p) for p in filenames]
merged_dataframe = pd.concat(dataframes, axis=1)
merged_dataframe.to_csv("merged.csv", index=False)

#reading the file that contains all the models for all the 
participants
cl = pd.read_csv("merged.csv", header=None).dropna()

#naming the rows
cl.index = ["ch{0}".format(i+1) for i in range(64)]["predicted","error","accuracy"]

#calculating the mean of each row
print(pd.Series.mean(cl, axis=1))

#getting teh mean of accuracy for each participant
for s in range(17):
    regg = pd.read_csv("reg{0}.csv".format(s+1), header=None).dropna()
    regg.index = ["ch{0}".format(i+1) for i in range(64)]["predicted","error","accuracy"]

    print(pd.Series.mean(regg, axis=1)[66])
```

I didn't find anything other than mord module.
I want to do a leave-one-out cross validation, and I have to just keep one of the samples for the test.

PS.
I am following instructions in this link:
http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/JWarmenhoven/ISL-python/blob/master/Notebooks/Chapter%206.ipynb
  I get the following error with doing exactly as they have done:
 module 'glmnet' has no attribute 'ElasticNet'

*However, they do not cover ordinal regression.

Comment: Show us what you have done (for example, the codes you have written).

Comment: I have split my data set to train and test:
import numpy as np
import mord as m
c = m.OrdinalRidge() #Default parameters: alpha=1.0, verbose=0, maxiter=10000
c.fit(scale(X_train), y_train)
mean_squared_error(y_test, c.predict(scale(X_test)))

Comment: I updated the question with the code I have written for using mord.OrdinalRidge and the error I get for leave-one-out cross-validation.

Comment: I have updated the question with my whole code, it has been the best thing I could write. I don't get any errors, but my final result is not consistent with previous analyses. So, I assume I have understood sth wrong there, probably about coding the regression procedure. I have my comments on what I mean by each block.

Answer (score -2):

You can use sklearn for this,

```
from sklearn import linear_model

regr_lasso = linear_model.Lasso(alpha=0.1)

regr_ridge = linear_model.Ridge(alpha=1.0)

regr_elasticnet = linear_model.ElasticNet(random_state=0)
```

Refer below links for more details,
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_lasso_coordinate_descent_path.html

Comment: I believe s.he is doing an ordinal classifier. What you propose solves a regression problem.